# Optimize Data Type in MONGO (c#)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

i have read this benchmark about 3 different database here:

http://blog.cubrid.org/dev-platform/nosql-benchmarking/

As i read, i see that MongoDB is "in memory database", so if all data of DB can be
loaded into RAM the performance of DB are very good. Otherwise will be very poor.
I read that MongoDB is good for project with "not amouth of data".

I have investigated on my first project in order to optimize every Document.

I see that my Document that have BYTE field will be converted in Int32 by Mongo!

```
public partial class i_Room
    {
        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(ObjectIdGenerator))]
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

        public global::System.Byte TypeRoom; 
        public global::System.Byte ModeRoom;
    }
```

The field "TypeRoom" and "ModeRoom" is converted in Int32 in MongoDB: i use MongoVUE in order to introspect the Database data. I think that this is very dangerous for memory.

So my question is: what i need to to in order to optimize BYTE data in Mongo?

Answer (score 0):

Except if you are using billions of records this won't hurt too much. (int32 is only 4 bytes)

You could instead use the bson type binary if you want. this is the equivalent of byte[].

Answer (score 0):

Because BSON's binary data type is variable length and also includes a 1-byte subtype field, it has an overhead of 5 bytes, so storing a single byte as binary takes 6 bytes.

You are better off storing it as a 4-byte integer.